# Virtualize a CPU without AES-NI

Tags: virtual-machine, aes, cpu, virtualization

I have an application with AES-NI compiled it, but supposedly select the implementation at runtime based on cpuid. I want to test if it really functions correctly on an old CPU without such dedicated instructions. VirtualBox cannot help because the CPU is the same. How can I do such a test without having access to an old CPU?

Comment: Just fake the returned result of CPUID (`and ecx, ~(1<<25)`).

Comment: @MargaretBloom: But if the program erroneously executes an instruction this fake old cpu should not have, it will continue to work, rather than cause a bus error.

Comment: Of course, but that's another problem from the one you asked. Specifically, since AES-NI doesn't satisfy the [Popek and Goldberg requirements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Popek_and_Goldberg_virtualization_requirements) it cannot be disabled in a virtual machine natively. You need a VM that do a full JIT (not just patching the critical instructions). VMware seems to be able to do that but only for the ESX (read expensive server solutions) versions.